# Looping all integer array elements using c while loop

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to loop an array of integers using pointer, but I get a strange values..

```
int nums[1] = { 1 };
int *p = nums;
while(*p != NULL) {
    cout << " LOOPING, p is " << *p << endl;
    p++;
}
```

When I am running, I am getting the next output:

```
 LOOPING, p is 1
 LOOPING, p is -858993460
 LOOPING, p is 4454504
 LOOPING, p is 3032019
```

Why I am get those strange values? I should see only "1", because I am looping until I get NULL pointer, and on each loop I move the next pointer.

Comment: You seem to be expecting the array to be NULL-terminated. That's not the case. Are you perhaps somehow confusing this with string literals?

Comment: Yes, I got confused with string literals.. can some one explain me why I got minus on the reputation?

Comment: Some people vote very harshly on questions that seem too basic. But it's a valid question, so here's a +1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> while(*p != NULL) {
> ```

The comparison is wrong for 2 reasons:

- `*p` is an integer, not a pointer like `NULL` implies
- the array isn't 0 terminated, so even if `NULL` is treated like a fancy 0, it won't work

You could try:

```
int nums[] = {1, 0};
while(*p)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are going beyond the array's bounds and looking at garbage values. Your array has size one, and contains `1`. So the condition in the while isn't met (or maybe at some point it gets med by pure chance).

Answer (score 3):

Your condition is wrong, the pointer will not be NULL in the end of the array, so what is happening is that you are going beyond the array bounds.

Also, using the `*` on the pointer takes the value at the memory it points at. So `*p` in your case means "take the value that p is pointing at".

Answer (score 2):

The other answers already cover why your code doesn't work - just wanted to add another option for looping:

```
int main()
{
    int nums[] = { 1, 5, 7 };

    int *pEnd = nums + sizeof(nums)/sizeof(int) - 1; // point to last element
    int *p = nums;

    while(p <= pEnd) {
        cout << " LOOPING, p is " << *(p++) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int GetSize(int a[]){
    int ptr=0;
    while(a[ptr]!= NULL){
        ptr++;
    }
    return --ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while you can try the below code:

```
int nums[] = {1, 0};
int *p = nums;
while(*p){
    cout << *p;
    p++;
}
```

Do note, that if you decide to add more numbers to your array after the zero, they will not be recognized upon iteration.

> ```
> nums[] = {1, 0, 1, 2}
> ```
>
> will only return
>
> ```
> 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In case of an int array the way we can point a pointer variable to last of that array is by doing this.
x = base_address + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int) -1;
The "-1" is for adding twice the base address. so if we do
p = x;
p will point to end element of an array.

it is like accessing an array element by index.